# Bandwidth value change each time the script in run in hdrcde function

Tags: r

The following code give different values of bandwidth everytime I run it.
I use a Mackey-Glass time series 1500 data, double, negative and positive data.

```
library(hdrcde)
myfile = ("C:\\Users\\ernest\\Desktop\\A Rcode\\testfile.txt")
y <- read.table(myfile, header=FALSE,col.names=c("A"), dec=".")

HDRlevelVal <- 0.99 
x <- y$A
hHDR <- hdrbw(x,HDRlevelVal, gridsize = 100)
HDRhat <- hdr.den(x,prob=100*(1-HDRlevelVal),h=hHDR)
print (hHDR)
print(HDRhat)
```

Any idea of what happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The bandwidth and HDR are computed using a Monte Carlo method, so it will give different results each time. If the differences are too large, increase the size of the Monte Carlo sample.

Comment: Thank you Rob. Can you confrm that I must increase the nMChdr value? Tank you.

Comment: Well I said "increase the size of the Monte Carlo sample" and if you read the help file it says that `nMChdr` is "the size of the Monte Carlo sample". Can I make it any clearer?